# Can we validate the time with the help of timestamp in solidity?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

The current time is timestamp.And the cooling period is stored inside a map while at the time of minting.
I tried to check whether the assetcoolingPeriodEnd time reaches or not. I intentionally make it to fail for my test case

```
    uint256 assetCoolingPeriodEndTime = _realTokenStorage()
        ._assetCoolingPeriodEndTime[assetId];

    uint256 currentTime = block.timestamp;
    console.log("currentTime:", currentTime);

    console.log("assetCoolingPeriodEndTime:", assetCoolingPeriodEndTime);
```

require(
currentTime >= assetCoolingPeriodEndTime,
"asset restricted by the owner"
);

I am expecting it to revert but it is not reverting.
The response I got for the call is
currentTime: 1688098632,
assetCoolingPeriodEndTime: 1690690627.

Can anyone help me to find out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
require( currentTime >= assetCoolingPeriodEndTime, "asset restricted by the owner" );
```

This condition expects `currentTime` to be greater or equal `assetCoolingPeriodEndTime`, otherwise it throws an exception.

However your `currentTime` value (starts with `168`) is lower than `assetCoolingPeriodEndTime` (starts with `169`). That's why it throws the exception - and an uncaught exception reverts the call.